# Which model(machine learning/ neural nets) to use for a selective input?

Tags: python, algorithm, nlp, artificial-intelligence

With an input of a paragraph containing multiple statements or a story as one variable, labels such as parts of speech, annotations such as place, person, organization etc as another variable and target variable containing a set of questions, identified as part of the paragraph e.g.

```
Column 1: *Sentences                      
Person1 makes novel reading lovable. However, his oration is very bad.                   
He works as a sales agent at XYZ in NZ*

Column 2: *Labels
{Noun: {Person1, dictionary},        
Verb: {reading, oration},            
Organization: {XYZ},                 
Location: {NZ}}*                      

Column 3: *Target Variables
Where does person1 live?
How is his taste in oration?
Which organization does person1
How does person1 help others?*
```

Based on the above input data, which algorithm takes them as input?
NOTE: The idea is, if a new set of statements are given, questions are to be generated based on the similarity of the paragraph & the labels associated